# Cannot convert value of type 'Int' to expected argument type 'String'

Tags: swift, string, casting, swift2, int

Hi guys i have created this code:

```
let array = [
    Enemy(imageNamed: "Slide 2"),
    Enemy(imageNamed: "Slide 1"),
    Enemy(imageNamed: "Slide 3"),
    Enemy(imageNamed: "Slide 4"),
    Enemy(imageNamed: "Slide 5"),
    Enemy(imageNamed: "Slide 6"),
    Enemy(imageNamed: "Slide 7"),
    Enemy(imageNamed: "Slide 8"),
    Enemy(imageNamed: "Slide 9"),
    Enemy(imageNamed: "Slide 10")
]

var level1 = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(array.count)))
    NSURL(string: level1)
    level1.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(texture: level1.texture!, size: level1.size)
    level1.physicsBody?.dynamic = true
    level1.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = BodyType.level1
    level1.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 0
    level1.position = CGPoint(x : background.size.width - 465, y : background.size.height - 218)
    level1.zPosition = 12
    addChild(level1)
```

> error: But on the line "NSURL(string: level1)" i get the error "Cannot
>   convert value of type 'Int'to expected argument type 'String'"

I would be very grateful if someone could show me a solution

Comment: Even if you convert the integer to a string, it is not an URL. What do you expect `NSURL(string: level1)` to be?

Comment: do you have any suggestions than for i have only just begun learning swift and would be very grateful

Comment: You probably want to select a random element from the array, but up to now you have a random number. So `let enemy = array[level1] ; enemy.physicsBody = ...` might be want you want. I have no idea what the purpose of your `NSURL(string: level1)` expression is. – And please *format* the code!

Comment: this works thank you so much if you tell me how i will up your reputation

Comment: If you're going through SpriteKit stuff just as a way to learn Swift, then you are taking a rough road to get there.  The Stanford iTunes course was extremely valuable for me.  Just google "stanford swift course itunes" and one of the first hits is the free iTunes course recently updated for iOS 9.

Answer (score 0):

This unwraps the Integer in a String, and based on what I have seen, should work for what you need.

```
NSURL(string: "\(level1)")
```

Comment: Almost there! the error disappeared however on the next line: "level1.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(texture: level1.texture!, size: level1.size) "  I get the error value of type int has no member physics body

Comment: An integer does not have a physics body. I believe you need to take a random item from your array, and then it will work!

`var theEnemy = array[level1]`

Then take 

`theEnemy.physicsBody` etc.

Answer (score 0):

you able to convert the integer to a string, but it is not an URL .

something like this :

```
let fileUrl = NSURL(string: filePath)
```

> An NSURL object represents a URL that can potentially contain the location of a resource on a remote server, the path of a local file on disk, or even an arbitrary piece of encoded data.

[Apple NSURL Document](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/)